# How to lookup entire column in excel depending on the column header value?

Tags: excel

I have a table and i want to lookup all values from an column based on a value i write in one cell. So if I write for example "Column 2" in a certain cell, it will lookup all the values from column 2 in the table. Similar to Vlookup but not the exactly the same.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What will happen to the values that are "looked up"?  Do they appear in a big list somewhere or are they aggregated into a summary value?

Comment: Appear in a big list, just the same as copy-paste all the values in the column in to another sheet. I am just moving the values in to another table so i can use them for calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In row 1, starting from column B, there are the headings of the columns: "Column 1", "Column 2" etc.

In A2:
`=INDIRECT("r"&ROW()&"c"&COLUMN(B1)+MATCH("Column 2";B$1:H$1)-1;FALSE)`

Paste this function down to the cells below A2.

Replace "Column 2" to a reference of the cell where you want to enter the heading that should be searched for.

B1 must be replaced by the first cell of the headings row in case this is not B1. H$1 must be the last cell of the headings row. The `MATCH` function will return the number of the column that is searched for according to its heading. The `INDIRECT`fun